# Calling notifyDataSetChanged reversing the position's order, is this a bug?

Tags: android

I'm developing one android application in which I'm using one customized `ListView` which extends `BaseAdapter`, In which I have placed two  TextView's and one button to delete the corresponding row from the list and also from the original data,

Whenever I call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` function the value of the position get reversed, am I doing anything wrong ?, Is there any other correct way to do this without the position get reversed ?

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

private int pos = position;

public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(context, "Click-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

});

holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View view) {

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: please provide the codes. Then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Ok post your cursor code. Or make sure you are using sorting in cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of on click for button in the every row in the list I just used context menu and performed the actions needed and updated the list and now its working.

Actually this is not the solution for my question and its just an alternative.