# Issue with customized adapter button click in ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, android-arrayadapter

I'm having a strange problem with a ListActivity working with a custom ArrayAdapter.
The list items are bounded to data through customized getView, and contains few text views and a button.
When Clicking the item's button, I'm opening a new activity according to the button pressed Tag, which contains the data item id.

Thing is, 
sometimes a click on a button of a certain item actually performs a click on other item's click, or so it looks like.
It's really strange, it act as if the button I've clicked lost focus to other one, that was clicked instead.
When using standard buttons I can actually see that there's some kind of mess with the focus on the list buttons that jumps from one to another.

I haven't figured out the scenario, but i suspect it's related somehow to the multiple calls to getView in the background.

that's my adapter's getView implementation:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View v = convertView;
    Context context = App.getContext();
    if (v == null)
    {
        // if the view is empty, init
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // add click listener to the item button
        Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b);
        OnClickListener lsn = new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                // when clicked we want to open the new activity with the selected id
                int id = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(mActivityContext, otherActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("ID", id);

                mActivityContext.startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        b.setOnClickListener(lsn);
    }

    ItemData currItem = m_Items.get(position);

    // Some fields data bindings to currItem

    Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b);
    btn.setEnabled(currItem.isButtonEnabled);
    btn.setTag(currItem.getID());

    return v;
}
```

That's my list definition on the layout:

```
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/android:list" 
          android:fadingEdge="none" android:divider="@color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="2dp" 
          android:background="@color/transparent" android:focusable="false" 
          android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

---

**Important Update:**

After some more tests i noticed that there is some consistency on what item is getting falsely clicked. it's always the mirror item. i.e when clicking on the first item in the list, when i get other item it's always the last!

e.g If there's 3 items in the list, the first and the last sometimes refer to each other but never to the middle item, and the middle item is always working as expected.
As if somewhere there's another list with the reverse order of items, and sometimes i get the mirror index instead of the regular and visible one...

That's really strange! most likely i'm doing something terribly wrong but i can't think of a situation that this can happen.

I've converted the array adapter to a class extends baseAdapter with an arrayList but the behavior continues...

**Last Update...**
So I found up that this issue is happening only when the notifyDatasetChanged is running in the background. however I can only reduce the calls for one each 2 seconds. that causing the problem to be harder to catch but it's still there...

ANY clue?

Comment: Is the issue after you have made any changes to the list of objects in the Array? If so, have you refreshed the listView?

Comment: I'm most confused by the fact that there are two buttons referenced.  The button that would fire the click event (referenced by R.id.b) is not the same button that has the tag attached (referenced by R.id.button).  I don't see how the Activity is ever started with the proper id value!

Comment: Can you add the full code for the ListActivity?  The issue might lie with how the getView method is called/setup.

Comment: And what is the difference between Button b and Button btn?  It seems that the tag is never set for Button b.

Comment: @Devunwired - you're right, my bad when copying the code. fixing.

Comment: @Wizetux - the list is constantly getting updates in the background and calling the notifyDatasetChanged. however while having the problem the items are just updating and the list count and order are the same.

Comment: @Bryan - there's a lot of code involved, it'll take me some time to get the relevant parts, but the flow is pretty simple, the adapter is bound to the listview and getting constant updates and calls to notifyDatasetChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I have to wonder if the issue is in your OnClick function. is the "v" that you are getting the tag from the 'v' that is defined in the OnClick definition, or based on scope is it the v that you define in the first line of the getView function?  Try changing the variable name to something more clear for the compiler, and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: ok, right. i assumed that because it should be a different scope it doesn't matter. but i've changed it. the problem is still there...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Wizetux about using a better variable name for your convertView variable, use something instead of 'v'.

However, I also think that instead of overriding the onclick of the view, could you either call or use the onListItemClick of the ListActivity class that you are extending (assuming that your code is in a class that extends ListActivity)?

Comment: well the onClick is actually the button click event, that i want to be pressed, not the whole item press. do you think it's should be an issue?

Comment: No, from the button, you should still be able to determine which list item, or list element, the button is on.  If you change the name of the first 'v' variable, the one that is set from the passed-in convertView variable, it will be easier to troubleshoot and debug what is going on.

Comment: I am still looking into this.  It is a tricky issue.  For some reason, and from what you said, only sometimes the wrong id is passed into the intent.  There seems like an issue with some confusion as to which button's onClick got fired... One question is when the wrong id is passed into the intent extras, for which button is that id?

Comment: My feeling is that the onClick events for each button are set in the right way, and the problem lays somewhere on the focus of the buttons in the list. I think that something causing the button focus to move to other one and then when the click occur it fires the wrong button event.
the really strange part is the consistency issue, in 3 items list the first and last sometimes get each other clicks, and the middle one is fine. as for 5 items list 1-5 and 2-4 getting sometimes confused, while 3 works...

Comment: Another thing I've not mentioned, when i click on a button in the list for long time, i can actually see the click animation jump from the button i've clicked and other button in the list - the same one i'm sometimes get as the wrong click and tag. the click animation jumps between the two buttons, that's really strange...

Comment: You had mentioned this before, but now you can actually see it happening, that the onclick event is being executed for a different button than the button that was clicked.  It does seem like the button gets associated with one list element, but the onclick method is associated with a different list element.

Comment: Ok,
I've tried disable all notifyDatasetChanged and saw the problem's not happening anymore. i think that's my issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229095/calling-notifydatasetchanged-reversing-the-positions-order-is-this-a-bug).
but for me using a context is not an option...
any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should directly define the onClickListener since it is being declared and defined from within the same method.

Also, I am not sure that the button definition and onClickListener for the button should inside the condition "If (v = null)"...

Example of directly defining the onClickListener instead of using the variable:

Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.b);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
    //the onClick code
  } 
});

Comment: I've moved the listener outside the v=null section and also directly defined the onClick listener. No change...

Comment: Have you ran the program using the eclipse debugger? If not, it might help to put a breakpoint in the onclick of the Button b button.  Post what the value of the button tag is, what the view position is, what the position of the list element is, and any other variable value is that you think might help. And we will continue to help you troubleshoot this complicated issue.

Comment: I'm indeed debugging with eclipse and logging info. currently i've added touch and focus events to the buttons.
the focus event never fires, but the touch event does.
i can now see that when clicking on the button the touch event is usually fired twice, most of the times with the same view tag, but often one of them is with the wrong tag, the one of the other list item. after the touch event is fired, i can see the click event, and in it, sometimes even if both of the prior touch events are getting the same correct tag, the click event is getting the wrong one!
I really appreciate the help!!

Comment: One more question, why are you using two different buttons in the getView for the same R.id.b button?  Try using just one variable for your button. For example, "b.setEnabled(currItem isButtonEnabled);", instead of "btn setEnabled(currItem isButtonEnabled);".

Comment: During the process I've changed this to work with the viewHolder pattern so it's no longer an issue.

Comment: Well I still don't have a solution, but at least i know the source of the problem... I'll try to workaround it somehow. any suggestions will be appreciated... thanks!

Comment: I thought you said that you changed your project to work with the viewHolder pattern, so the issues that you were asking about are no longer an issue?

Comment: no... it was regarding your comment about the b button reference.
i've found that the problem is related to the notifyDatasetChanged, that while it called there's a point the list is reverted and so the indexes are wrong. still looking for a solution...